# Laravel 5.6: DOMPDF Doesn't Save PDF Files

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.6, dompdf

I am using the DOMPDF Wrapper for Laravel 5 to create a PDF from a view.

```php
<?php

$customer = Customer::findOrFail(Auth::user()->id);

return PDF::loadView('backend.profile.includes.pdf.pdf', 
    compact('customer'))->save(public_path('pdf/resume/test.pdf'));
```

When I access the related page, the file isn't saved in the public folder. Nothing happens.

Comment: you can check this link for better solution . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60795346/how-to-save-dompdf-file-to-storage-and-name-the-file-dynamicly-in-laravel/74942859#74942859

Answer (score 0):

You should use Laravel's filesystem to save the data from DOMPDF to a file.  I'm not sure how your code looks that actually renders the PDF, but here is a general idea.

First, make sure to link the "public/storage" directory to "storage/app/public".  Laravel can do this for you with the following command.

```
php artisan storage:link
```

Then you could do something like this to render the document with DOMPDF and save the file.

```
use Dompdf\Dompdf;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

$dompdf = new Dompdf();
$dompdf->loadHtml($view);
$dompdf->setPaper('letter', 'portrait');
$dompdf->render();

$file = $dompdf->output();
Storage::put('public/test.pdf', $file);
```

See [this article](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/filesystem) for more details.